# Does WebView2 function when inside an app launched with SW_HIDE command?

Tags: delphi, webview2

I know, a very esoteric and specific question, but I'm spending ages trying to figure out why none of the navigation events get triggered when I'm trying to get a web page capture inside an app that was launched with `ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('WebpageFetcher.exe'), nil, nil, SW_HIDE)`, while they do get triggered when using `SW_SHOW`.

Tried using both `WVBrowser1.CreateBrowser(WVWindowParent1.Handle)` and `WVBrowser1.CreateWindowlessBrowser(WVWindowParent1.Handle)`.

Both work perfectly when using `SW_SHOW`, but I'm guessing that because the main form is hidden when using `SW_HIDE`, the `OnNavigationCompleted` and `OnCapturePreviewCompleted` are not triggered.

However, `OnDOMContentLoaded` does get triggered in all cases.

Might it be that, when using SW_HIDE, the app doesn't have a proper messaging loop running and these events don't get propagated...?

Overlooking something very basic, I'm sure. I don't need to see any form, just get the capture.

If anyone has any pointers, appreciated.

Comment: See [Fighting WebView2 Visibility on Initialization](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Jul/14/Fighting-WebView2-Visibility-on-Initialization)

Comment: @PeterWolf Helped me out a lot! Many thanks!